# PHImageManager.requestImageForAsset returns nil when creating thumbnail for video

Tags: ios, swift

For some videos, the requestImageForAsset completes with a UIImage that's nil. For other videos it works fine and I haven't figured out why yet.

```
func createThumbnailForVideo(video: PHAsset) -> Future<NSURL> {
    let promise = Promise<NSURL>()
    let options = PHImageRequestOptions()
    options.synchronous = true

    imageManager.requestImageForAsset(video, targetSize: CGSizeMake(640, 640), contentMode: .AspectFill, options: options) { (image:UIImage!, info) -> Void in

        if image == nil {
            println("Error: Couldn't create thumbnail for video")
            promise.error(MyErrors.videoThumb())
        } else {
            if let thumbURL = self.savePhotoAsTemporaryFile(image) {
                promise.success(thumbURL)
            } else {
                promise.error(MyErrors.videoThumb())
            }
        }
    }

    return promise.future
}
```

I also get back the info for the request but I don't know how to interpret the information:

```
[PHImageResultIsDegradedKey: 0, PHImageResultWantedImageFormatKey: 4037, PHImageResultIsPlaceholderKey: 0, PHImageResultIsInCloudKey: 0, PHImageResultDeliveredImageFormatKey: 9999]
```

Comment: Sounds like a bug, especially if it's specific to some videos and not others. [Have you reported it](http://bugreport.apple.com)?

Comment: Haven't reported it as I wasn't sure it was a bug. I guess I can do that but the last one I reported was back in October and I haven't heard anything back. Do they reply to bug reports?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I was having the same problem today. For me I had to add the option to download the image if necessary. I think the image manager had a thumbnail size version available but since I hadn't allowed it to fetch the actual image from the network it would return nil on the second call back. So to fix this I created a `PHImageRequestOptions()` object like this:

```
var options = PHImageRequestOptions()
options.networkAccessAllowed = true
```

Then send this as a param with your request:

```
PHImageManager.defaultManager().requestImageForAsset(asset, targetSize: size, contentMode: PHImageContentMode.AspectFill, options: options) { (image, info) -> Void in
    if (image != nil) {
        cell.imageView.image = image
    }
}
```

Once I did this the second callback image was not nil. I think it is still a good idea to guard against having a nil image so you don't set the image view's image to nil. I don't think you can assume that the image will always be there. Hope this helps!

EDIT: Just to clarify. In my case for each request, the closure would be called twice. The first time the image was not nil and the second time it was. I think this is because a thumbnail sized version was available but the full size was not. It needed network access to fetch the full size image.

Comment: networkAccessAllowed = true, didn't help in my case.

Comment: The docs say ```networkAccessAllowed```'s default value is YES, however the headers and the observed behavior indicates that the default is in fact NO.

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks.

Comment: Worked for me too. Thanks!

Comment: @jamone As of now, the docs says default value of isNetworkAccessAllowed  is false. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photos/phimagerequestoptions/1616934-isnetworkaccessallowed

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the problem. The contentMode was .AspectFill but should be .AspectFit. I guess I could get it working by tweaking PHImageRequestOptionsDeliveryMode and PHImageRequestOptionsResizeMode if I read the comments. However .AspectFit was what I was looking for.

```
enum PHImageContentMode : Int {

// Fit the asked size by maintaining the aspect ratio, the delivered image may not necessarily be the asked targetSize (see PHImageRequestOptionsDeliveryMode and PHImageRequestOptionsResizeMode)
case AspectFit
// Fill the asked size, some portion of the content may be clipped, the delivered image may not necessarily be the asked targetSize (see PHImageRequestOptionsDeliveryMode && PHImageRequestOptionsResizeMode)
case AspectFill
```

}

Answer (score -1):

I had similar issue, but it was for photos not video. I had missed to specify the media type.

```
self.assetsFetchResults = [PHAsset fetchAssetsWithMediaType:PHAssetMediaTypeImage options:nil];
```

Above line solved the issue for me.