# PHImageManager throws exception while generating image

Tags: ios, swift

I have this problem. When I try to generate image from asset using this method:

```
   manager.requestImageForAsset(asset, targetSize: CGSize(width: asset.pixelWidth, height: asset.pixelHeight), contentMode: .AspectFit, options: option, resultHandler: {(result, info)->Void in
            thumbnail = result!
```

As you can see I have put in the target size the width is "asset.pixelWidth" which I believe it returns the actual width of the asset, therefore I want the generated image to have the same dimensions as the original asset.

For some reason this throws an exception "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional" on some images in my camera roll, Not all of them, but some of them. What is more interesting is that when I put the target size 100 for example for both width & height. It works on all assets on camera roll without exceptions.

Honestly I don't understand what the heck is happening here. So if can someone give me a clue that would be great.

This is the whole method used:

```
func getFullAssetImg(asset: PHAsset) -> UIImage {
        let manager = PHImageManager.defaultManager()
        let option = PHImageRequestOptions()
        var thumbnail = UIImage()
        option.synchronous = true

        print(asset.pixelWidth)
        print(asset.pixelHeight)

        manager.requestImageForAsset(asset, targetSize: CGSize(width: asset.pixelWidth, height: asset.pixelHeight), contentMode: .AspectFit, options: option, resultHandler: {(result, info)->Void in
            thumbnail = result!
        })

        return thumbnail
    }
```

and this is how it's called:

```
let image = self.getFullAssetImg(asset)
```

--------UPDATE--------

When I added an option with value:

```
options.deliveryMode = .FastFormat
```

It worked! if I make this option with value **HighQualityFormat** it will throw exception

It's working now but if any one can tell me how this option solved my problem that could help other people.

Comment: What is the error thrown?

Comment: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional

Comment: And btw asset.pixelWidth have a value. I printed it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dears,

After spending one whole day i at last know whats happening here:

Thanks to this link: [PHImageManager.requestImageForAsset returns nil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28369400/phimagemanager-requestimageforasset-returns-nil-when-creating-thumbnail-for-vide)

I noticed an option called networkAccessAllowed. This options makes the manager able to process an image on the cloud.

What was going wrong was that i was testing an image that was based on icloud so it was returning nil.

However this is the last piece of code I got to make things work:

```
        func getFullAssetImg(asset: PHAsset) {
        let manager2 = PHImageManager.defaultManager()


        print(asset.pixelWidth)
        print(asset.pixelHeight)
        //let imageSize = CGSize(width: asset.pixelWidth, height: asset.pixelHeight)

        let options = PHImageRequestOptions()
        options.deliveryMode = .FastFormat
        options.synchronous = true
        options.networkAccessAllowed = true

        manager2.requestImageForAsset(asset, targetSize: PHImageManagerMaximumSize, contentMode: .AspectFit, options: options, resultHandler: {(result, info)->Void in
                if let thumbnail = result{
                    self.fullResolutionImages.addObject(thumbnail)
                    print("Full Resolution Image Added")
            }
        })


    }
```

Hope it helps someone afterwards.

Thank you